# How to make StackExchange-esque quotation block in LaTeX?

Tags: box

I mean this one:

> looks quite pretty. Optionally with a background.

Thanks in advance

**Edit** This may be a good way to start:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mbox0}{standard jigsaw, opacityback=0.2, colback=gray, bicolor, frame hidden, arc=4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{mbox0}
\begin{tabular}{|p{12pt}}
Prolog
\end{tabular}
\end{mbox0}

\end{document}
```

Now the left bar just needs to be thicker and *round*

Comment: You have the `leftbar` environment, defined by the `framed` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview, border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mbox0}{enhanced, 
                     colback=white,
                     frame hidden,
                     boxrule=0pt,
                     borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{gray!50, line cap=round}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mbox0}
Prolog
\end{mbox0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Prolog as an example of content... What a good choice!